# Zend framework 2: Invalid instantiator of type "NULL" for "Zend\Form\FormInterface"

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

I am not able to instantiate my forms via DI due to strange exception.

Here is the code snippet to reproduce exception I got

```
include 'Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
    'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
        'autoregister_zf' => true
    )
));

include 'Zend/Di/Di.php';

$di = new Zend\Di\Di();
$form = $di->get('Zend\Form\Form');
```

I always get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Di\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Invalid instantiator of type "NULL" for "Zend\Form\FormInterface".'

What am I doing wrong? Any help and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify ZF2 version. The problem occurs with version 2.1.1. I must say that with version 2.0.7 my code worked well. I've got this crash after update to ZF 2.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I digged into this and indeed an exception is thrown. Try running following:

```
$def = new \Zend\Di\Definition\RuntimeDefinition();

var_dump($def->getMethods('Zend\Form\Form'));
```

This will dump all methods that `Zend\Di` will understand as "injection methods". The output will be something like

```
array (size=23)
  '__construct' => boolean true
  'setData' => boolean false
  'setHydrator' => boolean false
  'setBindOnValidate' => boolean false
  'setBaseFieldset' => boolean false
  'setValidationGroup' => boolean false
  'setInputFilter' => boolean false
  'setUseInputFilterDefaults' => boolean false
  'setPreferFormInputFilter' => boolean false
  'setWrapElements' => boolean false
  'setOptions' => boolean false
  'setFormFactory' => boolean true
  'setPriority' => boolean false
  'setMessages' => boolean false
  'setObject' => boolean false
  'setUseAsBaseFieldset' => boolean false
  'setName' => boolean false
  'setAttribute' => boolean false
  'setAttributes' => boolean false
  'setValue' => boolean false
  'setLabel' => boolean false
  'setLabelAttributes' => boolean false
  'prepareElement' => boolean true
```

As you can see, method `prepareElement(FormInterface $form)` is marked as injection method. That is because (as of current [Di introspection strategy](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.1/library/Zend/Di/Definition/IntrospectionStrategy.php#L31-L34)) `prepareElement` is defined in interface [`Zend\Form\ElementPrepareAwareInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.1/library/Zend/Form/ElementPrepareAwareInterface.php), and that since `2.1.0`.

Since injection methods are marked to be called by `Zend\Di` after the object is instantiated, `Zend\Di` is hereby failing to find an instance for `Zend\Form\FormInterface` (which isn't `Zend\Form\Form`).

So as you can see the change has nothing to do with `Zend\Di` in this case. You could eventually [report it](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues) or alter the introspection strategy to suit your needs.

I personally don't think `Zend\Di` should call that method, nor that the method should be part of an `*Aware*` interface.